# Stripe throwing webhook 500 code error when on checkout.session.completed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup Stripe in my project, and when I try to pay for something I have the code inside the Stripe webhook which checks for successful payments, but the payment is never successful, even though the webhook on logs give me 200 code. Can you guys help me with this?

api/webhook/stripe/route.ts

```
import stripe from "stripe";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { createOrder } from "@/lib/actions/order.actions";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const body = await request.text();

  const sig = request.headers.get("stripe-signature") as string;
  const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!;

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Webhook error", error: err });
  }

  // Get the ID and type
  const eventType = event.type;

  // CREATE
  if (eventType === "checkout.session.completed") {
    const { id, amount_total, metadata } = event.data.object;

    const order = {
      stripeId: id,
      eventId: metadata?.eventId || "",
      buyerId: metadata?.buyerId || "",
      totalAmount: amount_total ? (amount_total / 100).toString() : "0",
      createdAt: new Date(),
    };

    const newOrder = await createOrder(order);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", order: newOrder });
  }

  return new Response("", { status: 200 });
}
```

lib/actions/order.actions.ts (creates an order)

```
"use server";

import Stripe from "stripe";
import {
  CheckoutOrderParams,
  CreateOrderParams,
  GetOrdersByEventParams,
  GetOrdersByUserParams,
} from "@/types";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { handleError } from "../utils";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../database";
import Order from "../database/models/order.model";
import Event from "../database/models/event.model";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
import User from "../database/models/user.model";

export const checkoutOrder = async (order: CheckoutOrderParams) => {
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!);

  const price = order.isFree ? 0 : Number(order.price) * 100;

  try {
    console.log("created order session");
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            currency: "usd",
            unit_amount: price,
            product_data: {
              name: order.eventTitle,
            },
          },
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      metadata: {
        eventId: order.eventId,
        buyerId: order.buyerId,
      },
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/profile`,
      cancel_url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/`,
    });

    console.log("done redirecting")
    redirect(session.url!);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export const createOrder = async (order: CreateOrderParams) => {
  try {
    await connectToDatabase();
    
    console.log("creating order")
    const newOrder = await Order.create({
      ...order,
      event: order.eventId,
      buyer: order.buyerId,
    });

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newOrder));
    console.log("order created")
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
};

// GET ORDERS BY EVENT
export async function getOrdersByEvent({
  searchString,
  eventId,
}: GetOrdersByEventParams) {
  try {
    await connectToDatabase();

    if (!eventId) throw new Error("Event ID is required");
    const eventObjectId = new ObjectId(eventId);

    const orders = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "buyer",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "buyer",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$buyer",
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "events",
          localField: "event",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "event",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$event",
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          totalAmount: 1,
          createdAt: 1,
          eventTitle: "$event.title",
          eventId: "$event._id",
          buyer: {
            $concat: ["$buyer.firstName", " ", "$buyer.lastName"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            { eventId: eventObjectId },
            { buyer: { $regex: RegExp(searchString, "i") } },
          ],
        },
      },
    ]);

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orders));
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
}

// GET ORDERS BY USER
export async function getOrdersByUser({
  userId,
  limit = 3,
  page,
}: GetOrdersByUserParams) {
  try {
    await connectToDatabase();

    const skipAmount = (Number(page) - 1) * limit;
    const conditions = { buyer: userId };

    const orders = await Order.distinct("event._id")
      .find(conditions)
      .sort({ createdAt: "desc" })
      .skip(skipAmount)
      .limit(limit)
      .populate({
        path: "event",
        model: Event,
        populate: {
          path: "organizer",
          model: User,
          select: "_id firstName lastName",
        },
      });

    const ordersCount = await Order.distinct("event._id").countDocuments(
      conditions
    );

    return {
      data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orders)),
      totalPages: Math.ceil(ordersCount / limit),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
}
```

I've already double checked my env variables and all of them are fine, I double checked the code and I couldn't point out any errors. Also, in the try catch blocks, the catch never throws anything inside my console or within the browser, I actually am redirected where I'm supposed to, but the ticket that I want to buy never shows.

On top of that, I provided this code to Gemini and, following its instructions for debugging still lead me to nowhere. Any light on this, please?

Comment: So your webhook returns 200 and you received `checkout.session.completed` event? If you open the PaymentIntent Id (pi_xxx) on Stripe Dashboard what do you see?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. when I open PaymentIntent ID I get payment succeeded, guess that's why I'm redirected correctly. But, even so, the ticket I bought doesn't show, because of the 500 error code

Comment: So it looks like everything on Stripe side succeeded. It comes to your `createOrder ` function. Was it triggered and do you see any error before or after triggering?

Comment: I've added the question with additional code. Inside checkoutOrder, which was triggered when I applied for payment, the "created order session" was console logged, but none of the others were. Seems like I never create an order.